# Merging 2 columns until the lastrow

Tags: excel, vba

I'm simply looking to merge or concatenate two columns consisting of first and second names into its own column onto a different sheet.

As the source of the 2 columns is a live page, I cannot edit it so I am looking to put the merged result onto another sheet and leaving the 2 columns on the live sheet as they were.

The length of the columns can change constantly as new names can be entered so it would have to go to the lastrow.

Not sure how to do it to the lastrow, if anyone could help that would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `='Sheet1'!A1 & " " & 'Sheet1'!B1` then copy down a few hundred more than you think you will ever need.

Comment: Thank you for that will that update every time a new name might be entered into the live sheet? also, can you explain how my question was a duplicate?

Comment: `Not sure how to do it to the lastrow, if anyone could help that would be great!` the link explicitly answers the implied question.

Comment: And yes it is live, The formula will always be current.  Just drag/copy the formula down far enough to cover everything.  It can go past, if no data is in the cells it will return a blank cell.

Comment: Fair enough thanks Scott!